# Composer how to specify install directory

Tags: installation, composer-php

Hi I've recently downloaded Laravel as a PHP framework, I've installed composer and have got that working, I've got it to create my project as per the Laravel website

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist
```

However when I use the above line this installs my project in the c:\users\guti directory however I want it to be installed in c:\xampp\htdocs.

I've seen another question on stackoverflow and it talks about amending the composer.json file but I'm not sure whether this is the route I should be taking as I've done a computer search for this file and this file exists as part of the laravel framework so does it make sense to amend this file?

Any composer experts on hand to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You should specify your destination directory where you want to create the project, from the command prompt, type `cd C:\xampp\htdocs` then press enter. After that, type following code on the command prompt and press enter

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel my-laravel-project
```

Here `my-laravel-project` will be your project folder.
The `composer.json` file is used to setup some configurations (for Dependency management) during installation of the package via packagist.
Visit [getcomposer.org](http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#dependency-management) for more information.

Comment: Hi thanks, but when I try the above I get the following error message `[InvalidArgumentException] Project directory /xampp/htdocs is not empty` I don't understand I've had this errror message before and it was because the file already exists however this is not the case here as I have already removed the laravel folder from here @RecoveringSince2003 any ideas?

Answer (score 121):

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel .
#                                       ^
#           this dot (.), important! ---´
```

Installs in your current directory =)

Comment: Using laravel 5.2 it then made a new folder called laravel, so I don't thinks this works any more.

Comment: just fyi @giantcowfilms I just tried this and it works like a charm. :) Thanks allmyshoesarewet

Comment: @ThomasLe Interesting. Maybe it behaves differently on different OSs?

Comment: Works perfectly on Windows 7 with Laravel 5.4. This is something that's always annoyed me. Thankkk yooouuu !

Comment: On mac this is not working. It creates a new folder called "laravel" inside the current folder.

Comment: this does not work, it creates a folder named laravel inside my directory

Comment: `composer create-project laravel/laravel .` this worked for me to create laravel project in existing folder.

Comment: It does work, don't forget the 'space dot' at the end

Comment: I get the following error: `Could not delete /var/www/html/.:`

Comment: Make sure that the folder is empty

Answer (score 8):

Whenever

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel .
```

Doesn't work properly for whatever reason, I just

```
 laravel new temp
```

And then move the contents of the new application into the folder I do want ; )

Answer (score 6):

I needed to do this myself. In the directory I wanted it installed, I did:

```
laravel new --force .
```

And it seems to be working well so far.

Comment: Perfect! ````-f```` also works as shorthand for force. Without the force it says ````Application already exists```` (even for empty directory)

Comment: I tried this on my Windows 10 machine with PHP 7.4.3. At first, I got an error: `Server error: 'GET http://cabinet.laravel.com/latest.zip' resulted in a '522 Origin Connection Time-ou' [...]`. So I updated laravel installer: `composer global require "laravel/installer"`. Not I got the following error: `Cannot use --force option when using current directory for installation!`
Still, thank you for the advice I didn't want to downvote. Perhaps you want to update our answer?

Answer (score 3):

This works for me on Ubuntu 20.04, Composer version 2.1.6:

```
cd your-directory  
composer create-project laravel/laravel ./
```

Comment: This works for me on Mac Ventura with iTerm/zsh.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

1. `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel directory-name`
2. Move files to preferred folder if needed (e.g. to ../)

---

**Why** don't `laravel new /.`?

1. `laravel new project-name` not always works good on different systems, so you need to edit PATH variable multiple times to add laravel command to cli (at least on OSX it's not that easy as on Ubuntu).
2. `composer create-project --prefer-dist .` may not work because of not empty directory (e.g. in JetBrains IDE's, which creates folder .idea/ which doesn't shows in IDE's 'project' view, only on 'project files'). Exception message looks like

`[InvalidArgumentException]

  Project directory ./ is not empty.`

So, if you know what you doing, do as you wish, on the other way, especially if you want as few problems as possible, do the steps from the top lines of this answer.

P.S. I'm speaking english not as good as i want to do, so, anyone, feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 0):

can try
`laravel new tmp && cp -R tmp/. . && rm -rf tmp`

`laravel new tmp` will create a new project store in tmp directory

`cp -R tmp/. .` will copy all file and directory from tmp into current directory

`rm -rf tmp` will remove the tmp directory

Comment: Please improve your answer by explaining it